# Is there a way to batch-find unlinked text URLs in the body text of all my posts and link them?

Tags: functions, urls, bulk-import, bulk-edit

**Context**: I used a plugin (WP All Import) to import Excel rows into WordPress posts, but some cells have multiple URLs. Since Excel only supports one hyperlink per cell, I have a bunch of plain text URLs that are unlinked scattered around my site.

Is there a way to scan every WordPress post and convert every plain text URL to a clickable URL?

Comment: To manually edit a large batch of content like this I'd likely use the https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/ plugin and do a a search and replace in the content (backing up everything first) and replace with something like <a href="$1">$1</a> - the plugin allows you to preview the effects of the search and replace.

Comment: Sounds really useful. I'll look into this. Thanks.